# The most appropriate questions to get quality end-user feedback during prototype testing?

Tags: usability-testing, prototype, user-feedback

The project I'm working on at the moment is in the prototype stage. As we have several versions of final prototype done in PDF, we decided to test it.

To get the most reliable answers as feedback we need to ask quality questions.

At the moment I have prepared the following questions and would like feedback or advice from experienced UX designers/developers:

1. What subject is the app dedicated to?
2. What's your overall impression of the interface: what's convenient, inconvenient, odd, etc?
3. Please evaluate the convenience of information representation in scale from 
   0 to 10.
4. Is the ordering information located in convenient place?
5. Please view this prototypes and consider, which is more convenient for you and why?
6. Is there a need to place an additional product types menu and where?
7. Is the "Products" block located in convenient place?
8. What associations and feelings are evoked by the "Partners" block?
9. Does the block "Facts" seem interesting to you and why?
10. Does the block "Reviews" seem interesting and helpful to you and why?

Etc.

Comment: Questions are unique to the test at hand, there is no perfect (or most appropriate) set that covers all. You need to tailor your questions, Google has a good list of "[how to write good user testing questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+write+good+user+testing+questions)". If you're at a paper prototype stage - are you just asking people to look at the paper and judge it (bad idea), or is in a guided interactive paper prototype?

Comment: Its not a guided prototype, just static obvious schema. The problem is that we cannot consider what implementation is best and have to decide between some more uniqueness or some more functionality. Or may be I'm vainly trying to intervene into the work of designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not appear that you are actually *testing* your prototype at all. You're showing individuals (perhaps not even adequately vetted target users) a paper mockup and asking them "what do 'ya think?"

**User Testing** is a structured observation of the user actually *doing*. It is a detailed process that involves:

1. recruitment of participants that represent your user base
2. developing test protocols
3. defining structures tasks for user to complete
4. defining scenarios in which those tasks exist
5. *observing* the user perform those tasks
6. collecting qualitative and quantitative data based on those *observations*
7. perform post-test comments & questionnaire

User Testing is *not* just walking up to someone you think might be a "user" and asking them open ended questions. Data received from showing a person a mockup and asking "Is the 'Products' block located in a convenient place?" is nearly useless. It lacks context. It lacks purpose. It lacks any connection to a real work flow.

*I don't care if someone thinks the 'Products' block is located in a convenient place.* What I care about is if the UI allows the user to complete their work flow in the most straight forward way possible. You have to have them *execute* that work flow in order to figure that out! A properly conducted user test allows you to *observe* if the block is in the right place or not.

**Post Test Questionnaires** are not free form questions designed to ask the user "what would you do?" It is your job to figure out what to do, not the users.

You can again find many examples of [user testing questionaries](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=user%20testing%20questionnaire) on your favorite search engine. They come in many forms, but here is a somewhat generic one:

[image]

Things to notice:

- It doesn't ask open ended questions
- Responses are on a 3-, 5- or 7-point scale (or other type of *scale*)
- It doesn't ask for advice
- Questions are *functional*, asking how well the UI did in helping the user *reach their goal*

You can certainly add some open ended questions to your questionnaire, such as "what are the 3 things you liked the most?" or "what 3 things did you like the least?", but they (1) are at the end and (2) don't represent the bulk of your data gathering.

**But it's all on paper!** Doesn't matter. You can find a great deal of information on [how to perform a paper prototype user test](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20perform%20a%20paper%20prototype%20user%20test). Just one of those links, "[Paper Prototyping As A Usability Testing Technique](http://usabilitygeek.com/paper-prototyping-as-a-usability-testing-technique/)" at Usability Geek, breaks it down very well. Among the information is who you'll need:

Paper prototypes can be used to conduct usability testing of any type of user interface – be it a website, mobile application or software. To be able to do so, you need the following people:

> **Real Users**: As stated by Jakob Nielsen, 5 users should be able to identify about 85% of all usability problems. These users will interact with a paper version of the user interface that is being tested.
>
> **A Facilitator**: Usually a usability professional and his/her role is to record the issues raised during the meeting. Where necessary, the facilitator needs to probe into the issues raised so that these are well documented. Since the ideas of the people present may be conflicting at times, the facilitator needs to act as a mediator between the different parties.
>
> **A Human Computer**: This person (typically the lead developer or someone who knows how the system is supposed to work) manipulates the paper prototype so that it can provide the feedback based on the user’s interaction. The human computer will not explain or give hints to the users about how the interface is supposed to behave so that the users are left entirely on their own to perform the tasks that they have been assigned.
>
> **Observers**: These people are typically members of the development team. Their role to observe and interpret the users’ interactions with the paper prototype.

If you read up on user testing you'll notice that the only major difference between a paper prototype and a computer prototype is that a human is flipping paper around, rather than a computer flipping screens. All the other participants are the same!

Answer (score 0):

At the end you can also ask them to talk about their feelings about working with your prototype and then extract users first impression from that, create a table of feelings and then cluster similar hedonic and pragmatic attributes that they felt in the page. Then try to find solutions for possible negative feelings on that, that is the way that you can touch the user experience in action and also you gave them an opportunity with fully freedom to talk about their overall feelings.
I hope that helped :)

Comment: Do you have any examples of this? It would be really helpful

Comment: Yeah, in a big scope I've done it in my master thesis: https://repository.asu.edu/attachments/143300/content/Eslamifar_asu_0010N_14430.pdf